# MSSql full-text search for words abbreviated with dots

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have been struggling with the following query:

```
select * from table_name where contains((field1,field2),'"S.E.N.S"');
```

Following is the text I have in field 1:
"**S.E.N.S Productions**"

If I search for "**production**" I get the result, but not for "**S.E.N.S**".

Any idea regarding how to get the desired result ? Thanks.

---

Update: Sql Server version is 2005 with SP3.

---

Update: Well, it is quite weird. When I set the full-text to use noiseENG.txt the query in my question works fine. But everything stored in the database is in Turkish and all the settings are set accordingly, including noiseTRK.txt. "S.E.N.S" is not a word in Turkish nor in English as far as I know. I can set it to noiseENG.txt to get it work, but I doubt that would be appropriate. Can anyone know/think of a reason why noiseTRK.txt would break in above query ? Thanks.

P.S. I have tested with unmodified noise files as well as single-letters-removed version of Turkish noise file.

Comment: read up about special characters in full text search. I think FTS  treats any special character as a word break.

Comment: Which word breaker (not noise file) are you using?  English or Turkish?

Comment: I am not at the level of fully understanding all the details of mssql. but I followed the steps described here (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/908441) to install Turkish support in full-text index. So, when I create the full-text index, I choose the column to be indexed and then choose Turkish (or English)  from the next column (language for word breaker). Choosing Turkish in here do not work for the above described case whereas English does. I am unsure about the difference between word breaker and noise file though.

Comment: That's the answer.  The Turkish word breaker breaks the words on punctuation like I describe in my answer (s e n s).  The English one breaks the word into both "sens" and "s.e.n.s".  The rules for the word breakers are different (and undocumented).  I wrote an app to test them all to see how they are broken up by language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, it may not work for SQL 2005.

As I recall, for the string "S.E.N.S Productions", the SQL 2005 FTS (Full Text Search) word breaker will ignore the punctiation, and break the string into individual letters (S E N S) and the word "Productions".  Single letters are, by default, noise words, and therefore won't be included in the index.

You can do a couple things:

1. Edit your noise word list and remove the single letters and rebuild your index
2. Upgrade to a later version of SQL, as the word breaking behaviour changes to corretly return your result in 2008.

Comment: Thanks for putting me in right direction. I did check out the noise word list and not pay attention to single letters. I know what exactly the issue is now. The table that I deal with has more than 8 million rows in it. So I will try your suggestion during the off times and post how it went.